# Cardinality of the conjugate class of $\sigma$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a permutation in $S_{12}$, $\sigma=(1,3,5)(2,9)(4,12)(6,11)(7,10,8)$.
How can I find the cardinality of the conjugate class of $\sigma$?

I know an element conjugated has form $(abc)(de)(fg)(hi)(jkl)$ with $a,\cdots,l\in\{1,2,3,.....,12\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want the size of the orbit of $\sigma$ under conjugation by the elements of $G$.  You can use the Orbit-stabilizer theorem.  First find the size of the centralizer $C(\sigma)$ of $\sigma$, that is, the set $\{g : g \in G \mid g^{-1} \sigma g = \sigma \}$. This group $C(\sigma)$ is the stabilizer of the element $\sigma$ under this action.

Comment: $|S_{12} : C(\sigma)|=|Cl(\sigma)|$

Comment: $|Cl(\sigma)|={12! \over {3*2*2*2*3}}$

Comment: @GiuliaB. That is not quite right. Note that you have elements of the centralizer that permute the 3-cycles, and elements that permute the 2-cycles. The denominator should be $3^2\cdot 2!\cdot 2^3\cdot\cdot 3!$